# Difference between Router and Component render?

Tags: reactjs, routes, frontend

I'm fairly new to React. It might be a dumb question but what would the difference between rendering a component like:
`<Component />`
and rendering it like `<Route path="/" component={Component}/>`

Comment: The first one is the normal React component. When you create a component and want to use it in another component, you write things like that. The second one is very similar but a <Route> is a custom component from React router, you can specify a path for it and so it only renders in that specific route

Comment: Thank you @konekoya that makes so much sense!